# how to insert a restriction in fee

Tags: attributes, xsd

This is my XML. It looks like I did the correct code, but it still seems not valid. I would like to restrict the `fee` so that it must have exactly 2 decimal digits:

```
     '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <bundle>
     <business type="entertainment">
     <name>Ice Skate Gallery</name>
     <contact>
     <person_name>James Druid</person_name>
     <phone>555-4409129</phone>
     <email>druid@druid.com</email>
     <address>
     <street>1149, southwest avenue </street>
     <zip>890610</zip>
     <state>CA</state>'
```

and this is my XSD:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

     <xs:element name="bundle">
     <xs:complexType >
     <xs:sequence>

     <!--</xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>

     <xs:complexType name="business">
     <xs:simpleContent>
     <xs:extension base="xs:string">
     <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
     </xs:extension>
     </xs:simpleContent>-->

     <xs:element name="business"> 
     <xs:complexType> 
     <xs:sequence>

     <!-- <xs:extension base="xs:anyType"/>
     <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:complexType>-->

     <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>

     <xs:element name="contact">
     <xs:complexType>
     <xs:all>
     <xs:element name="person_name" type="xs:string"/>
     <!--<xs:element name="phone" type="xs:string"/>-->
     <xs:element name="phone">
     <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:pattern value="\d{3}-\d{7}"/>
     </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
     </xs:element>
     <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="address">
     <xs:complexType>
     <xs:all>
     <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
     <!--<xs:element name="zip" type="xs:string"/>-->
     <xs:element name="zip">
     <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:minLength value="5"/>
     <xs:maxLength value="6"/>
     </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
     </xs:element>

      <!--<xs:element name="state" type="xs:string"/>-->
      <xs:element name="state">
      <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="2"/>
      </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>


      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:all>
      </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
      </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <!--<xs:element name="admission">
      <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>-->

      <!-- <xs:element name="fee">
      <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:byte">
      <xs:attribute name="currency" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>-->

      <xs:element name="admission">
      <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="fee"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type"/>
      </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:simpleType name="typeFee">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
      <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
      </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:element name="fee">
      <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="typeFee">
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="currency" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>





      </xs:sequence><!--this is for business attribute-->
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type" use="required"/>
      </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>
```

Can you help me to correct this?

Comment: Can you add a complete XSD (not just fragments)? Your example is small and it's OK to have errors in the XSD, but your XSD should *at least* be a well-formed XML. Please edit your code and include a well-formed XSD.

Comment: In your title you ask about how to insert a restriction in an *attribute*, but in the question you actually want a restriction in the contents of the `fee` element. Which is the real question?

Comment: i have repost my post and insert the full xsd. i'm really hope for your instant reply.:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have a well-formed XSD and that your are not interested in inserting a restriction in an *attribute* as the title of your question says, but inserting a restriction for the `<fee>` element in your XML instance.

It seems (from your fragments of code) that you tried to declare two elements and one type, but mixed things up a bit. Let's start with your `admission` element. It's a *complex type* since it contains an attribute and other elements. It's not a *simple type*. You could declare that it allows a `fee` child element using a `sequence`. After the sequence, you can declare the attribute:

```
<xs:element name="admission">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="fee"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I'm using defaults here. If you don't use `maxOccurs` and `minOccurs` in the sequence and element, the default is exactly 1. So only *one* child `<fee>` element will be allowed. The `fee` element is included as a *reference*. That means that it is declared somewhere else in the schema.

The `type` attribute was declared to be of type `xs:string`. You might want to restrict that as well, using an *enumeration* of values (`paid`, `not-paid`, etc.) or a regular expression. But this will work for now. After the file validates you can tune the schema and adapt it to your needs.

You had already declared the simple type `typeFee` and the restriction you defined for it is correct. It will limit the decimal contents to a number *greater* than zero with 2 decimal positions (so the minimum is `0.01`). You just need to place it as a top level element (as child of `<xs:schema>` so it can be referenced from the other elements:

```
<xs:simpleType name="typeFee">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The `fee` element has simple content but it's not a simple type because it has an attribute, so you declare it as a complex type containing simple content and *extend* its type (which is `typeFee`) so that it allows one attribute:

```
<xs:element name="fee">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="typeFee">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="currency" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

To validate your file you should place those three elements as children of the `<xs:schema>`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
    <xs:element name="admission">...</xs:element>     
    <xs:element name="fee">...</xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="typeFee">...</xs:simpleType>     
</xs:schema>
```

You can save a lot of time reading a tutorial on XML Schema, and [*generating* a schema from an instance](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html). The generated schema may be a good starting point because at least it validates the instance you provided, so you can use it as a prototype to guide the development of your schema. Sometimes, however, generated schemas can be unnecessarily complex.